# String copy using pointers in c++, during the copy the program is crashing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting an error while copying one string to another string using pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void String_copy(char* scr,char* des)
{
while(*scr!='\0')
    {

    *des= *scr;
    scr++;
    des++;

    }

}
int main()
{
    char *str1, *str2;
    str1="bharath";
    str2="ygftygyfrgtg";
    String_copy(str1,str2);
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    cout<<str2<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In below code you have undefined behaviour:

```
char *str1, *str2;
str1="bharath";
str2="ygftygyfrgtg";
```

you should assign string literals only to `const* char`, this also means you should not modify str and str2

you can fix above with:

```
char str1[] = "bharath";
char str2[] = "ygftygyfrgtg";
```

but you must also fix `String_copy` - so that it checks bounds of arrays being modified, ie. add additional parameter with max length of `des`, also dont forget to add '\0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ISO C++ **forbids** converting string constants to `char*` pointers.
Try something like this instead to define `str1` and `str2`:

```
char str1[]="bharath";
char str2[]="ygftygyfrgtg";
```

Your second problem is the `String_copy` function, where you just check one of the strings for the terminal `\0` character. Also you should add a `\0` to the `des` string (in case it was initially longer):

Something like this will work:

```
void String_copy(char* scr,char* des){

    while(*scr!='\0' && *des!='\0')*des++=*scr++;
    *des=0;
}
```

Note that you can copy **maximally** up to the length of your **shorter** string, since you did not allocate more memory anywhere.

Also if it is possible you should use **std::string**

Comment: You most certainly *can* assign the address of a string literal to a pointer, and the result is well defined--the string literal is statically allocated, so its address remains valid for the entire time the program runs. It's even entirely valid (for example) to do something like `char *foo() { return "some string";}` Even though "some string" looks vaguely like it could be local to the function, it's actually statically allocated, so it remains valid after the function returns.

Comment: @JerryCoffin While your example might work, this does *not* `char *str="some string"; str[0]='X';`

Comment: Correct--any attempt at modifying the contents of a string literal give undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin hmm so also : `char str[]="some string"; str[0]='X'` is undefined, which would render all the answers in this thread useless? `gcc` puts the `char* str` in a completly different memory location then the `char str[]` for me so maybe the fact, that modifying the str[] version works fine is just by luck and is compiler-specific. I also wonder if the fact that string literals are kept at fixed adresses and your example: `char *foo() { return "some string";}`  works, is guaranteed by the c++ standard, or just *virtually all* compilers handle it that way.

Comment: No--that defines an array of char, initializes the array from the string literal, then modifies the array (not the literal itself). That's perfectly acceptable. The problem arises when you try to modify the string literal itself.

Comment: As far as requirements go, yes, it's required that all (working) implementations use static storage for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

The two strings are different lengths but you only check for a zero terminator in one of them. Either use strings of equal length or check for the zero terminator in both (and decide what to do with the excess characters).

Comment: There are a number of other serious mistakes too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "bharath" is not of type `char*`.
Its actually a type `char const*` but the language (for comapability with C) allows auto conversion between the two. If you turn on your warnings (and treat them as errors) this will not even be allowed to compiler:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror sc.cpp
sc.cpp:36:10: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
    str1="bharath";
```

Now (that you have fixed this) you are suffering from the issue that the destination string could be shorter than src. Which will result in the same problem (writing to memory you dont own).